Simulator iOS 18 - iMessage-app : adding a vCard and sending -> "The recipient cannot receive this item via satellite."
New in Xcode 16 (not in Xcode 15)
When I try to use similar to send an attachment, I get a modal error that says:
"Unable to Send"
"The recipient cannot receive this item via satellite."
This happen is the simulator for iPhones w/ iOS 18, but not 17.5. This does happen on all simulators that emulate devices with and without satellite support.
This does not happen on a real device when I side-load.
Another changes is that sending between the two loopback accounts appear to use green bubbles now.
    let conversation = self.activeConversation
    if let msgFile = url {
        conversation?.insertAttachment(msgFile, withAlternateFilename: filename, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    

I'm inserting a vCard.
Anyone else seen this problem (and worked around it?)

You can't send messages on simulators

You can't send them to "real" accounts, but the simulator has two accounts that point to each other... that 's what isn't working, but did in (simulated) iOS17.5 and earlier. What's surprising is there has been OS support for satellite mode for maybe two years now?

This happens to me as well! Can't figure out how to get around it in IOS 18.

I'm not active updating Xcode 18 from RC, but I'll post again whenever I jump.
